# Defined clickable region while disabling links within?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a site where people can embed instagram videos. I have these show up as thumbnails, and I would like to have an overlay popup (containing the full size video) when they click on the thumbnail. Unfortunately, instagram's embed code comes with built in links and when clicked the video simply plays at the small size.

So my question is: How do I create an invisible overlaying region+link that will ignore the links of the underlying content? (I have the popups coded and working properly, just need to figure out how to disable the links)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a transparent div on top of the links you want to disable and give it a higher [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

```css
#links {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999; /* simulating that the target has a manually given z-index*/
}
#maskDiv{
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6); /* keeping it partially visible to demontrate it's there*/
  width: 200px;
  height: 42px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  z-index:1000; /* needs to be higher than the target div */
}
```

```html
<div id="links">
<a href="#">A functional link</a><br />
<a href="#">Another functional link</a><br />
<a href="#">A link masked by a div</a><br />
<a href="#">Another</a><br />
<a href="#">Last one is functional</a><br />
</div>
<div id="maskDiv"></div>
```

Comment: So simple. Thank you!